# Creating a login program using a text file

Tags: python, user-input

I'm trying to create a task manager program (in Python) that allows a user to login and view/add tasks. The user logins are stored in text file called `user.txt`. I'm struggling to validate the username and password so that they can login and access the menu of the task manager.

Disclaimer: I'm still a beginner.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
usernames = []
passwords = []


with open("user.txt", "r") as f1:

    for lines in f1:
        logins = lines.strip()
        logins = lines.split(",")
        username = logins[0]
        password = logins[1]
        usernames.append(logins[0])
        passwords.append(logins[1])

        user_name = input("Please enter your username:\n")
        pass_word = input("Please enter your password:\n")
        
        if user_name == username and pass_word == password:
            menu = input('''Please select one of the following options:\n
        r - register a user 
        a - add task
        va - view all tasks
        vm - view my tasks
        e - exit ''').lower()
```

This is the contents of the `user.txt` file:

```
admin, adm1n
```

When I entered the username and password from the user.txt file, I expected it to print the menu but that didn't happen.

Comment: Do you really mean to repeat the promopts for every line in the file?

Comment: You're calling `lines.split(",")`, which splits on exactly a comma.  But your textfile actually has comma-space.  So it thinks the password is actually `<space>adm1n`.

Comment: Try calling `lines.split(", ")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`password` has a leading space.  One way to fix it is to change:

```
    password = logins[1]
```

to:

```
    password = logins[1].strip()
```

When I run the code and enter `admin` and `adm1n`, I see the menu printed out.

Since you are a beginner, the simplest way to debug your code is to `print` variable values.  I did this to see that `password` has a leading space.